# User Input comparison with .txt

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Writing a code that quizzes a user with questions from a file, compares the user_input with the answers in a .txt file. Can't seem to wrap my head around why it doesn't compare the answers and does not increment the variable by 1 for each correct answer. Might it be because the script doesn't read the answer.txt file?

````
#!/bin/bash
clear
questions=$1
answers=$2
correct=0
wrong=0

while read line  #IFS = internal field Seperator
do
        echo
        echo $line
        echo
        echo "Your Answer:\c"
        read user_answer </dev/tty #reads answer from terminal
        if [ "$user_answer = $answers" ]; then
           correct =$((correct + 1))
        fi
done < $questions

echo
echo "Correct Answers: $correct "
echo "Wrong Answers: $wrong" ```
````

Comment: No spaces allowed before or after the `=` in an assignment. What exactly is `answers`, the name of a file containing the answers or a single string with the answers to every question. Either way, your comparison is wrong; it's not the answer to the current question.

Comment: Forgot to mention. the answers are only "yes" or "no". The initial plan would be to run the script with the a couple of excecution parameters: ./scriptname qfile afile. Where the user selects his own files but initially I named the answers file answers.txt. And the answers start with each new line.

Comment: Then you need to iterate over the answer file as well as the question file. I'll provide an answer.

Comment: @MOSARON : Besides the error in the `correct =...` line, I don't see any reference to `answers.txt` in your code. Maybe you pass this filename as parameter 2, but I also do not see that you would anywhere read from either $2 or $answers.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that both the question and answer files have the same number of lines. The `while` loop will read one line from *each* file at each iteration, using separate file descriptors for each file. Standard input will be left alone, to allow the user to enter an answer.

```
clear
questions=$1
answers=$2
correct=0
wrong=0

while IFS= read -r q <&3  # Read from descriptor 3
      IFS= read -r a <&4  # Read from descriptor 4
do
        echo
        echo "$q"
        echo
        echo "Your Answer:\c"
        IFS= read -r user_answer
        if [ "$user_answer" = "$a" ]; then
           echo "Correct!"
           correct=$((correct + 1))
        else
           echo "Wrong!"
           wrong=$((wrong + 1))
        fi
done 3< "$questions" 4< "$answers"   # Use 3 for questions, 4 for answers  
echo
echo "Correct Answers: $correct "
echo "Wrong Answers: $wrong"
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know that you can use descriptors. Still have a lot to learn!